# Delphi popup menu not working via uiautomation

Tags: delphi, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a library that I have extended to allow us to test interaction with Delphi StringGrids via the ms-automation library. When I make a call to the `showContextMenu` method, the library effectively calls the `popup` method of `TPopupMenu` (in `Vcl.Menus.pas`). This is a wrapper around the call to the `TrackPopupMenu` Window API, when called from the automation library, the calls result in no menu being displayed, when called via a button inside the application, then the menu IS displayed.

I've debugged it and it seems to pass the same information into the `TrackPopupMenu` calls, but doesn't get the same result.

This has me totally stumped.

I can't post the code for the application, but essentially the code looks rather like this ...

```
type
  TMyGridItem = class(TAutomatedStringGridItem)
  protected
    procedure SelectCell; override;
  public
    function ShowContextMenu: HResult; override; stdcall;
    function Invoke: HResult; override; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

function TMyGridItem.ShowContextMenu: HResult;
var
  gridTop, top: Integer;
  gridLeft, left: Integer;
  cell : IAutomatedStringGridItem;

begin
  gridTop := self.top;
  gridLeft := self.left;

  cell := self.getSelectedCell;

  left := (cell as TMyGridItem).CellRect.left -gridLeft + self.parent.left;
  top := (cell as TMyGridItem).CellRect.top -gridTop + self.parent.left;

  self.MouseDownGeneral(self, mbRight, [], left, top);

  result := S_OK;
end;
```

`MouseDownGeneral` populates the menu items with data and then calls the popup menu mentioned above.

The Automation Library I am using is located at [DelphiUIAutomation](https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation) , and for full disclosure it's my project.

This has me stumped, so does anyone have an idea where to start looking at why the 2 calls work differently?

- I have replaced the complex code above with a call to `popupmenu` directly, and this also does not work as expected.